# Clojure list comprehension where the number of bindings is not known (variadic 'for')

Tags: clojure, list-comprehension, variadic

What's a good way to create a variadic 'for' in Clojure?

I wrote this out:

```
(defmacro variadic-for
  [f colls]
  (let [bindings (map (fn [coll] [(gensym) coll]) colls)]
    `(for ~(vec (apply concat bindings))
       (~f ~@(map first bindings)))))
```

So I can use this like:

```
(variadic-for + [[1] [2] [3 4]])
```

and the result will be every possible sum, where each given collection represents the possible values for that binding.

Is there a better way to do this? I don't know of anything in the Clojure core that is used to create all permutations in this way, other than 'for'.

Comment: Could you clarify the desired result?  Is it `[6 7]`?  Also, what is the use case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe [`cartesian-product`](https://clojure.github.io/math.combinatorics/#clojure.math.combinatorics/cartesian-product) from [`clojure.math.combinatorics`](https://github.com/clojure/math.combinatorics)?

```
(defn variadic-for [f colls]
  (map #(apply f %)
        (apply clojure.math.combinatorics/cartesian-product colls)))

(variadic-for + [[1] [2] [3 4]])
=> (6 7)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think your macro implementation is great, but implementing it as a function has the advantage of increased composability. For instance, you can pass your `variadic-for` to a function. Here is an implementation of `variadic-for` as a function:

```clj
(defn combine2 [A B]
  (for [a A
        b B]
    (conj a b)))

(defn combinations [colls]
  (reduce combine2 [[]] colls))

(defn variadic-for [f colls]
  (map #(apply f %) (combinations colls)))
```

I believe there is already a `combinations` function in some library but implementing it yourself, as done above, is easy.

Here is something you cannot do if `variadic-for` is a macro:

```clj
(def combinatorial+ (partial variadic-for +))

(combinatorial+ [[1] [2] [3 4]])
;; => (6 7)
```

Comment: Identifying that 'combinations' is just left fold of combine2. Smart!